# Simplest way to create a webview app for my own use?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a simple application that will load a local html file for my Android 3.1 tablet to give presentations on. I'm not a programmer, but I read some tutorials about creating a simple webview app with Eclipse + Android SDK. But before I get dirty I wanted to know if there was a simpler way of just getting a simple app on my tablet that will in reality just be a full screen web browser. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with using a browser that that has a full screen mode? [Dolphin](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dolphin.browser.pad) has a full screen mode. Why bother creating an app, especially if you are not a programmer?

Comment: Because I can't seem to open a local file.
It's located in `Root/Download/Index.htm`, so I type file:///Root/Download/index.htm, doesn't work. file:///localhost/Download/Index/htm, doesn't work... file:///localhost/Root.... doesn't work.

Comment: The URL for a file in your download directory on your SD card looks something like: `file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/index.htm`. An easier way to deal with this sort of thing is to use a file explorer sort of application to browse for the file. I use [File Manager HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm.hd) on my tablet.

Comment: Also note that even if you manage to write your own program, you still won't be able to open the file without knowing the URL.

Comment: I wanted to put the html file in the local directory of the application.

Comment: Why...? If that's what you really want though then in answer to your questions in other comments, yes you will have to download the SDK, yes you will have to compile. Additionally you will have to put your files in assets or resources and then you'll have to learn how to load them properly... Not going to be that easy for a non-programmer.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be using WebView class with default properties. You can read more about WebView class on - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Hi Pritesh, thanks, but this still requires me downloading the SDK and compiling it manually?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a xml file that has the layout with the webview widget in it, and inflate it on your onCreate() using setContentView().

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Declare this at class level

```
WebView mWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(String URL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is essentially the code I will have to compile? [I read a tutorial here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-embed-a-webview-with-the-webkit-engine/) and it sounds pretty much the same to what you explained, no?